# totalview only recognizes some variables, executable lines

Tags: debugging, fortran, totalview

How can I make totalview offer access to all the variables in my code?

I'm trying to debug a Fortran90 program using totalview.  I compiled and linked with Intel's ifort, using the "-g" flag.  totalview can step through my program, but only offers "dive" for four of the variables in my subroutine, and many executable source lines have no box I can check to set an action point.  Of all the variables declared below, only cell_EW, cell_NS, area, and pct are available to dive later in the subroutine.

```
164  REAL, allocatable, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(in) :: lon, lat
165  REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:, :, :, :) :: area, pct
166  REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:, :, :), INTENT(in) :: in_flux
167  REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:, :, :), INTENT(inout) :: out_flux
168  REAL :: cell_EW, cell_NS
169  INTEGER status, ierr, dimid, nlon, nlat, ntimes
170  INTEGER i, j, k, LOGDEV, this_var, this_t
171  INTEGER jdate, jtime, this_date, this_time
```

another example: line 190 does not allow me to set an action point, and ntimes is unrecognized as a variable.

```
189  CALL calc_land_area(pct, cell_EW, cell_NS, lon, lat, area)
190  ntimes = SIZE(in_flux, 1)  ! first dimension is time
191  do i = 1, ntimes
```

Comment: Other than `-g` what compiler flags do you specify? I've not used totalview but the faq [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/totalview/#Compiling) says not to use optimisation flags. By default I think `ifort` will use `-O2`, so you might want to try explicitly stating `-O0` or similar. (actually `-g` may imply `-O0` but it can be overriden)

Comment: wow, @d_1999, you nailed it.  I had seen that FAQ and removed an explicit `-O2` flag (and set `-g`) for debugging, but it hadn't occurred to me to use an explicit `-O0`.  I recompiled with `-O0 -g` and all my variables are now available.  Many thanks!  If you add your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When variables are not available in inspection tools like gdb and totalview it's often because the compiler has optimised them away. This is hinted at in the totalview [faq](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/totalview/#Compiling)

> Don't compile your program with optimization flags while you are
>   debugging it. Compiler optimizations can "rewrite" your program and
>   produce machine code that doesn't necessarily match your source code.

As different compilers have different default optimisation levels (and potentially `-g` may have additional implications other than just including symbols) it's usually a good idea to include an explicit `-O0` or equivalent in order to disable any optimisation. Some compilers (e.g. gfortran version >= v4.8) provide a specific debugging optimisation level with the `-Og` flag as noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694107). This allows optimisations that don't impact on the ability to debug.