# fortran : invalid memory reference

Tags: fortran, physics, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

I encountered this error while solving the diffusion equation on fortran using alternating directional implicit(ADI) method.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

#0  0xffffffff
#1  0xffffffff
#2  0xffffffff
#3  0xffffffff
#4  0xffffffff
#5  0xffffffff
#6  0xffffffff
#7  0xffffffff
#8  0xffffffff
#9  0xffffffff
#10  0xffffffff
#11  0xffffffff
#12  0xffffffff
#13  0xffffffff
#14  0xffffffff
```

And here is my code

```
program HW1_1_ADI

implicit none 

real :: delx, dely, delt, dx, dy
real, parameter ::  a=0.7, m=0.1, eta=0.001, pi=3.141592
real, dimension(401,101,50) :: psi
real, dimension(201,101,50) :: psi2, psi_half
real , dimension(401) :: x
real, dimension(400) :: a_D, b_D, C_D, v_D, o_D
real, dimension(100) :: a_D2, b_D2, C_D2, v_D2, o_D2
integer :: i, j, n, imax, jmax, nmax, ihalf

open(1,file='HW1.txt')
2 format (101((400(e10.3,','), e10.3), /))

imax = 401
jmax = 101
nmax = 50
ihalf = (imax+1)/2
delx = 2.0/(imax-1)
dely = 1.0/(jmax-1)
delt = 0.2  * 10**3
dx = eta * delt / delx**2
dy = eta * delt / dely**2

! x-coordinate
do i = 1, imax
    x(i) = -1.0 + (i-1)*delx
end do

! initial condition
do i = 1, imax
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi(i,j,1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do
end do

do i = 1, ihalf
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi2(i,j,1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do
end do

! ADI
do n = 1, nmax-1
    do j=2, jmax
        do i = 2, ihalf
            b_D(i-1) = 1.0 + dx
            a_D(i-1) = -0.5*dx
            c_D(i-1) = -0.5*dx
            if (i == ihalf) then
                a_D(i-1) = -dx
            end if

            if (j==jmax) then
                if (i==2) then
                    v_D(i-1) = dy*psi2(i,jmax-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,jmax,n) + 0.5*dx*psi2(1,jmax,n)   
                else
                    v_D(i-1) = dy*psi2(i,jmax-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,jmax,n) 
                end if
            else
                if (i==2) then
                    v_D(i-1) = 0.5*dy*psi2(2,j-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(2,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi2(2,j+1,n)&
                    +0.5*dx*psi2(1,j,n)
                else
                    v_D(i-1) = 0.5*dy*psi2(i,j-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi2(i,j+1,n)
                end if
            end if
        end do

        call tridag(a_D,b_D,c_D,v_D,o_D,ihalf-1)
        
        do i = 1, ihalf-1
            psi_half(i+1,j,n) = o_D(i)
        end do
    end do

    ! boundary condition
    ! y=0
    do i = 1, ihalf
        psi_half(i,1,:) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do

    ! x=-1
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi_half(1,j,:) = cos(m*pi) - a*cos(3.0*m*pi)
    end do

    do i = 2, ihalf
        do j = 2, jmax
            b_D2(j-1) = 1.0 + dy
            a_D2(j-1) = -0.5*dy
            c_D2(j-1) = -0.5*dy
            if (j == jmax) then
                a_D2(j-1) = -dy
            end if
            
            if  (i==ihalf) then
                if (j==2) then
                    v_D2(j-1) = dx*psi_half(ihalf-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(ihalf,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi_half(ihalf,1,n)   
                else
                    v_D2(j-1) = dx*psi_half(ihalf-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(ihalf,j,n) 
                end if
            else
                if (j==2) then
                    v_D2(j-1) = 0.5*dx*psi_half(i-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(i,j,n) + 0.5*dx*psi_half(i+1,j,n)&
                    +0.5*dy*psi_half(i,1,n)
                else
                    v_D2(j-1) = 0.5*dx*psi_half(i-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(i,j,n) + 0.5*dx*psi_half(i+1,j,n)
                end if
            end if
        end do

        call tridag(a_D2,b_D2,c_D2,v_D2,o_D2,jmax-1)

        do j = 1, jmax-1
            psi2(i,j+1,n+1) = o_D2(j)
        end do

    end do

    ! boundary condition
    ! y=0
    do i = 1, ihalf
        psi2(i,1,n+1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do

    ! x=-1
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi2(1,j,n+1) = cos(m*pi) - a*cos(3.0*m*pi)
    end do

    ! reflection condition
    do i = 1, ihalf
        do j = 1, jmax
            psi(i,j,n+1) = psi2(i,j,n+1)
        end do
    end do
end do


do i = ihalf+1, imax
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi(i,j,:) = psi(imax+1-i,j,:)
    end do
end do

write(1,2) psi(:,:,2)

contains
    subroutine tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)
        implicit none
        integer n, nMAX
        real a(n), b(n), c(n), r(n), u(n)
        parameter (nMAX = 100)
        integer j
        real bet, gam(nMAX)
            
        if (b(1) == 0.0) print *, 'tridag: rewrite equations'
            
        bet = b(1)
        u(1) = r(1)/bet
            
        do j = 2, n
             gam(j) = c(j-1)/bet
            bet = b(j) - a(j)*gam(j)
            if (bet == 0.0) print *, 'tridag failed'
            u(j) = (r(j)-a(j)*u(j-1)) / bet
         end do
        
        do j = n-1, 1, -1
            u(j) = u(j) - gam(j+1)*u(j+1)
        end do
        return
        end subroutine
end program
```

What I'm curious about is that **it's good at first**.

At first, I set it up **imax=200**(maximum index of x-coordinate).

Here is original code.

```
program HW1_1_ADI

implicit none 

real :: delx, dely, delt, dx, dy
real, parameter ::  a=0.7, m=0.1, eta=0.001, pi=3.141592
real, dimension(201,101,50) :: psi
real, dimension(101,101,50) :: psi2, psi_half
real , dimension(201) :: x
real, dimension(100) :: a_D, b_D, C_D, v_D, o_D
real, dimension(100) :: a_D2, b_D2, C_D2, v_D2, o_D2
integer :: i, j, n, imax, jmax, nmax, ihalf

open(1,file='HW1.txt')
2 format (101((200(e10.3,','), e10.3), /))

imax = 201
jmax = 101
nmax = 50
ihalf = (imax+1)/2
delx = 2.0/(imax-1)
dely = 1.0/(jmax-1)
delt = 0.2  * 10**3
dx = eta * delt / delx**2
dy = eta * delt / dely**2

! x-coordinate
do i = 1, imax
    x(i) = -1.0 + (i-1)*delx
end do

! initial condition
do i = 1, imax
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi(i,j,1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do
end do

do i = 1, ihalf
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi2(i,j,1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do
end do

! ADI
do n = 1, nmax-1
    do j=2, jmax
        do i = 2, ihalf
            b_D(i-1) = 1.0 + dx
            a_D(i-1) = -0.5*dx
            c_D(i-1) = -0.5*dx
            if (i == ihalf) then
                a_D(i-1) = -dx
            end if

            if (j==jmax) then
                if (i==2) then
                    v_D(i-1) = dy*psi2(i,jmax-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,jmax,n) + 0.5*dx*psi2(1,jmax,n)   
                else
                    v_D(i-1) = dy*psi2(i,jmax-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,jmax,n) 
                end if
            else
                if (i==2) then
                    v_D(i-1) = 0.5*dy*psi2(2,j-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(2,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi2(2,j+1,n)&
                    +0.5*dx*psi2(1,j,n)
                else
                    v_D(i-1) = 0.5*dy*psi2(i,j-1,n) + (1.0-dy)*psi2(i,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi2(i,j+1,n)
                end if
            end if
        end do

        call tridag(a_D,b_D,c_D,v_D,o_D,ihalf-1)
        
        do i = 1, ihalf-1
            psi_half(i+1,j,n) = o_D(i)
        end do
    end do

    ! boundary condition
    ! y=0
    do i = 1, ihalf
        psi_half(i,1,:) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do

    ! x=-1
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi_half(1,j,:) = cos(m*pi) - a*cos(3.0*m*pi)
    end do

    do i = 2, ihalf
        do j = 2, jmax
            b_D2(j-1) = 1.0 + dy
            a_D2(j-1) = -0.5*dy
            c_D2(j-1) = -0.5*dy
            if (j == jmax) then
                a_D2(j-1) = -dy
            end if
            
            if  (i==ihalf) then
                if (j==2) then
                    v_D2(j-1) = dx*psi_half(ihalf-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(ihalf,j,n) + 0.5*dy*psi_half(ihalf,1,n)   
                else
                    v_D2(j-1) = dx*psi_half(ihalf-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(ihalf,j,n) 
                end if
            else
                if (j==2) then
                    v_D2(j-1) = 0.5*dx*psi_half(i-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(i,j,n) + 0.5*dx*psi_half(i+1,j,n)&
                    +0.5*dy*psi_half(i,1,n)
                else
                    v_D2(j-1) = 0.5*dx*psi_half(i-1,j,n) + (1.0-dx)*psi_half(i,j,n) + 0.5*dx*psi_half(i+1,j,n)
                end if
            end if
        end do

        call tridag(a_D2,b_D2,c_D2,v_D2,o_D2,jmax-1)

        do j = 1, jmax-1
            psi2(i,j+1,n+1) = o_D2(j)
        end do

    end do

    ! boundary condition
    ! y=0
    do i = 1, ihalf
        psi2(i,1,n+1) = cos(m*pi*x(i))-a*cos(3.0*m*pi*x(i))
    end do

    ! x=-1
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi2(1,j,n+1) = cos(m*pi) - a*cos(3.0*m*pi)
    end do

    ! reflection condition
    do i = 1, ihalf
        do j = 1, jmax
            psi(i,j,n+1) = psi2(i,j,n+1)
        end do
    end do
end do


do i = ihalf+1, imax
    do j = 1, jmax
        psi(i,j,:) = psi(imax+1-i,j,:)
    end do
end do

write(1,2) psi(:,:,2)

contains
    subroutine tridag(a,b,c,r,u,n)
        implicit none
        integer n, nMAX
        real a(n), b(n), c(n), r(n), u(n)
        parameter (nMAX = 100)
        integer j
        real bet, gam(nMAX)
            
        if (b(1) == 0.0) print *, 'tridag: rewrite equations'
            
        bet = b(1)
        u(1) = r(1)/bet
            
        do j = 2, n
             gam(j) = c(j-1)/bet
            bet = b(j) - a(j)*gam(j)
            if (bet == 0.0) print *, 'tridag failed'
            u(j) = (r(j)-a(j)*u(j-1)) / bet
         end do
        
        do j = n-1, 1, -1
            u(j) = u(j) - gam(j+1)*u(j+1)
        end do
        return
        end subroutine
end program
```

This works well.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You don't show how you are compiling, but if you are using gfortran you should consider [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3676322/3157076) and its answers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you learn how to use your compiler to help you diagnose these problems - when developing always turn on run time error checks. Here is what `gfortran` can tell you, note the `-fcheck=all` and `-g` flags, though I would recommend all the ones I use:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g -std=f2008  imax.f90 
imax.f90:160:12:

  160 |         if (b(1) == 0.0) print *, 'tridag: rewrite equations'
      |            1
Warning: Equality comparison for REAL(4) at (1) [-Wcompare-reals]
imax.f90:168:16:

  168 |             if (bet == 0.0) print *, 'tridag failed'
      |                1
Warning: Equality comparison for REAL(4) at (1) [-Wcompare-reals]
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
At line 166 of file imax.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '101' of dimension 1 of array 'gam' above upper bound of 100

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f998e9abd01 in ???
#1  0x7f998e9ac849 in ???
#2  0x7f998e9acec6 in ???
#3  0x5562d1681337 in tridag
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/imax.f90:166
#4  0x5562d1681971 in hw1_1_adi
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/imax.f90:72
#5  0x5562d1681f56 in main
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/imax.f90:149
```

From this it looks like you haven't adjusted the `nMax` parameter in `tridag` correctly - I suggest you also learn about allocatable arrays and how you can avoid this problem in a way which means you don't have to change your code for every different size you try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem was fixed by modifying the nMAX in the tridag subroutine. Your answer was very helpful to me. Best regards.

Comment: It might be useful to create a canonical (wiki answer?) on how to compile using debug flags? Most common compilers, e.g. ifort, gfortran, should be included.

Comment: We could also mention debuggers as well as plugins for editors, e.g. native debug for vscode.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but to be honest I can also see the value in showing an inexperienced user how to do it with their own code - if they provide a complete example like this one (why the downvotes?? let's encourage these guys!) it takes seconds to bang it through your favourite compiler and show them what to do with their own code. They are more likely to learn from, appreciate and remember that than a generic answer.

Comment: It was my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so I was immature. I'll ask you a proper question next time. Thank you to everyone who replied.