# Outout is affected for some weird silly reaons (print command as well as silly declaration of array)

Tags: fortran, subroutine, intel-fortran, abaqus

I am new to this community. I am using ifort compiler for my abaqus subroutine. I was using it effortlessly until the last 2 weeks I have been struggling a lot! It is just that my output is affected because of some silly reasons as follows

1. When I print any variables the problem gets fixed
2. When I use any variables that are passed in through my subroutine from abaqus to declare the dimension size, I only gets the correct result without printing anything, which is super silly. Here is an example. Here is a simple 2 elements and I am computing its stiffness matrix and so displacement, I will spare the loading etc but the point is u can clearly see each element has 4 nodes.
   So when I declare b matrix as 4 by 8 abaqus just gives an error. But when I use nnode and abaqus passes it I get correct result!! but nnode -4 absolutely![enter image description here]

Then I use a do loop for forming ba matrix! I don't understand why it is wrong! It is taking 10 days to fix this small problem so that I can apply in larger scale! I am using all the checks as can be seen.
I understand the printing problem has been discussed and the recommendation was to initialize variables as well as to check arrays are not used than they are bound to! In my case it looks like the access to the b matrix array is happening in a very mysterious way no matter logically the array is literally the same! I am attaching the code for your kind perusal. I hope this discussion will help many people to not to loose their time. Kindly please give any insights what you think of it!

I tried putting the dimension of b matrix as we know because  i knew we are modelling quad elements which have 4 nodes, so when i use b matrix as 4 by it gives wrong results but when i u se b matrix to define to 4 by 2*nnode wheree nnode is passed from abaqus to the uel subroutine then only it understand the limit. This is what I think!

Comment: It sounds like your code is broken, but we can't tell you how it's broken from your description. Please create a [mre], or search for questions here about how to use your compiler or debugger to help you work out how your code is broken

Comment: For example, using gfortran one can read about [its compile options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3676322/3157076). Other compilers, such as ifort, have similar. That question is a good start for what you need to look for with your compiler.

Comment: This kind of "random" behavior often shows up because of an array overflow. First, compile your code with all warnings and runtime checks enable, e.g. `ifort -warn -check`

Comment: @Biswabhanu Puhan ... please show your code!